# Oracle replace function on a string with single quotes and commas

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have a query in the form

```
SELECT REPLACE(text, 'a','b') 
FROM DUAL;
```

if the string text = `a','b','c`

How do I place the string in the replacd function so that it runs correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this using the alternative quote operator: `test := q'[a','b','c]';`

Or:

```
SELECT REPLACE(q'[a','b','c]', 'a','b') 
FROM DUAL;
```

More info [here](http://oraclelearningzone.blogspot.com/2012/07/alternative-quote-q-operator_16.html).

Here's another way to prove it in Sqlplus:

```
SQL> declare
     test varchar2(15) := q'[a','b','c]';
   begin
   dbms_output.put_line(REPLACE(test, 'a', 'b'));

   end;
   /

b','b','c

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Escape](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref336) each single quote with a second single quote:

```
SELECT REPLACE( 'a'',''b'',''c','a','b') FROM DUAL
```